# Convert string numeric values with comma as decimal separator to NUMERIC(10, 2)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion, string, decimal

I have an SQL table of varchar columns which contain Greek formatted numbers (. as thousand separator and comma as decimal separator)

The classic conversion

```
CONVERT(numeric(10,2),REPLACE([value],',','.'))
```

does not work because the . (thousand separator) kills the conversion

E.g try

```
CONVERT(numeric(10,2),REPLACE('7.000,45',',','.'))
```

I want to convert such values to numeric(10,2)

Any suggestions of how to handle it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(*If you are using SQL Server 2012 or newer, please see @wBob's [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/118083/30859) for a cleaner approach. The approach outlined in my answer below is only required if you are using SQL Server 2008 R2 or older.*)

You don't need (or want) the thousands' separator when converting to `NUMERIC`, regardless if it is comma, period, or space, so just get rid of them first. Then convert the comma into a period / decimal and you are done:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 2), 
               REPLACE(
                       REPLACE('7.000,45', '.', ''),
                       ',', '.'
                      )
              ) AS [Converted];
```

Returns:

```
7000.45
```

For the sake of completeness, I should mention that I also tried:

- `SET LANGUAGE Greek;`
- Looking at various format styles for [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql), but nothing applies here.
- The [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) function, but the input type must be a numeric or date/time/datetime value (that and it was introduced in SQL Server 2012, so not applicable to SQL Server 2008 R2 or older).

And nothing else seemed to work. I was hoping to find something more elegant than two `REPLACE` calls, but so far no such luck.

---

Also, just to mention, while not a pure T-SQL solution, this can also be accomplished via SQLCLR. And, there is a pre-done function that does this in the [SQL#](https://SQLsharp.com/?ref=db_118062) library (that I wrote) named **String_TryParseToDecimal**. This function is available in the Free version, and works in every version of SQL Server starting with SQL Server 2005:

```sql
SELECT SQL#.String_TryParseToDecimal('7.000,45', 'el-GR');
```

Returns:

```
7000.45000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 14):

What version of SQL Server are you using?  From SQL Server 2012 onwards you can use [TRY_PARSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126(v=sql.110).aspx) with its `USING culture` argument.  You can also use [PARSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213316(v=sql.120).aspx), the difference being `PARSE` will fail if the conversion fails and `TRY_PARSE` will return a `NULL`, eg

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( x VARCHAR(10) )

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES ( '7.000,45' ), ( 'xxx' )

SELECT x, 
    TRY_PARSE( x AS NUMERIC(10,2) USING 'El-GR' ) x
FROM @t
```

[image: test results]

HTH

Answer (score -1):

The following code worked in my case:

```
select convert(varchar,FORMAT(123456789.0258,'###,###,###.00','de-de'))
```

output: 123.456.789,03

Comment: or  select convert(varchar,FORMAT(cast(yourValue as numeric(10,2)),'###,###,###.00','de-de'))

Comment: it seems you are answering the reverse problem of what the OP asked. they don't want to format numeric values, they want to convert formatted varchar values to numeric.

Comment: Also, two notes: **1)** always specify a length for `VARCHAR`, `NVARCHAR`, `CHAR`, and `NCHAR` types. The default is 30 in some case and 1 in other cases, which makes for unmaintainable / error-prone code. **2)** you don't need the exact layout when using `#`. You just need one of them (e.g. `#`) for all digits but no thousands separator, or two of them separated by a comma (e.g. `#,#`) to get all    digits _and_ the thousands separator. Hence, `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), FORMAT(123456789.0258, N'#,#.00', N'de'));` returns the same output as what you are suggesting.