# Reading decimal mark comma with an external table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, number-formatting, polybase

SQL Server 2016, SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). Creating external tables with Transact-SQL and Polybase. How can we read decimals with a decimal mark, comma instead of dot?

When using `float` and `decimal`, it fails and throws an error. When using `money` data type it succeeds, but misreads decimals and integers are returned instead.

Revised the file format standard clause, no option to configure such a thing. Collation already set for my region.

Sample data:

```
2017;4;2017;601PPP;183,63;0
2017;4;2017;601PPP;183,63;0
2017;4;2017;601PPP;183,63;1.000,55
2017;4;2017;601PPP;183,63;2,5
2017;4;2017;601PPP;183,63;7,5
2017;4;2017;601PPP;405,28;17,5
```

Example of a create table that would fail to read the sample data:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[STG_Table] (
    field1           smallint     NULL
   ,field2           tinyint      NULL
   ,field3           smallint     NULL
   ,fieldn_2         varchar(10)  NULL
   ,fieldn_1         money        NULL
   ,fieldn           float        NULL
)
WITH (LOCATION='/STG_Table/',
    DATA_SOURCE = AzureDataSource, 
    FILE_FORMAT = FileFormat
);
```

Query used to read data:

```
SET @dynamicSQL = N'SELECT * INTO ##' + @someTable + ' FROM STG_' + @someTable 
EXEC sp_executesql @dynamicSQL
```

Specifying fields implies more cases to be added (working inside a procedure) and it can be avoided by configuring such a thing. I found more simple configuring this, than adding more code. No configuration found in database configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that interpreting '1.000,55' as a float isn't simple, but as a numeric [is possible](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/118083/36809). From that answer

```
select try_parse('1.000,55' as numeric(10,2) using 'es-ES') as x

x
-------
1000.55
```

I've tried every which way with other target data types. None work. Obviously a CAST() can be wrapped around the try_parse to get the desired final type.

So what I'd suggest is you define your external table with the difficult columns as varchar(n). Then define a view which reads the external table and uses try_parse to convert the difficult columns to the desired data type. This view is accessible to the application and end users; the table is visible only to the view.